# How is a lambda moved?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14, move-semantics

I don't understand how a lambda is moved. Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

struct Foo // non-copyable type
{
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete; // cannot copy
    Foo(Foo&&) = default; // can move
};

auto lambda = [p = Foo()](){
    std::string x{"lambda"}; 
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
};
// auto copied_lambda = lambda; // cannot copy due to Foo non-copyable init capture
auto moved_lambda = std::move(lambda); // we moved it

struct Functor // "simulate" a lambda
{
    std::string x{"functor"};
    void operator()() const
    {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
};

Functor functor; // initial functor object
auto moved_functor = std::move(functor); // moved it

int main()
{
    lambda(); // why does it display "lambda" since it was moved?
    moved_lambda(); // displays "lambda", was moved in, everything OK

    functor(); // doesn't display "functor", was moved
    moved_functor(); // displays "functor", was moved in, everything OK
}
```

As you can see, I declare a `Foo` non-copyable class (but movable) that I pass to the init capture of `lambda`, so `lambda` ends up being move-only. The lambda closure declares a `std::string` (which is movable). Next I move the `lambda` into `moved_lambda`, so I expect the `std::string` to be moved as well. However, when I invoke `lambda()` in `main()`, it still displays the old string, as if it wasn't moved at all.

I then "simulated" the lambdas with functors, and when moving `functor` into `moved_functor`, the initial `string` in `functor` is moved as well, so when I try displaying it in `main()` I get a null string. I am puzzled by this behaviour, why this inconsistency? I would have expected that a moved lambda (which internally is just a function object) would move its components and not copy them. My only explanation is that the local variables inside the `lambda` are `const`, so instead of moving them we copy them, but I'm not sure. Is this the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Functor` does not line up with your lambda. Your lambda actually looks like:

```
struct Functor // "simulate" a lambda
{
    void operator()() const
    {
        std::string x{"functor"};
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Hopefully that helps make clear why your moved-from lambda still prints `"lambda"`: the `Functor` had its `x` moved-from, but the lambda did not.

Comment: ohhh stupid mistake, of course, I see it now. Both answers are equally good, I'll accept yours since it came 1 second :) earlier.

Comment: To make the lamba do the same as the functor, you can set the x in the capture: `[x = std::string{"lambda"}]{ … }`. Also note that what is in `std::string` after it was moved is undefined so what you got may be valid even when both lambda and functor would do the same.

Comment: @haccks Thought yours was the better answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your examples aren't identical. The proper simulation of the lambda would be:

```
struct Functor // "simulate" a lambda
{
    void operator()() const
    {
        std::string x{"functor"};
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Note that `x` is now inside the function. The two examples now behave the same: they both print their local variables even though they were moved.

The explanation is simple: the inner variables don't get copied or moved because they don't exist at the time the functor/lambda are copied or moved. They get created & destroyed when their `operator()`'s are called.

Comment: Although interestingly if you change the lambda to `std::string xx{"lambda"}; auto lambda = [p = Foo(), xx](){ std::cout << xx << std::endl; };`, it still does print `lambda` both for `lambda()` and `moved_lambda()` ... https://ideone.com/XzAPZf

Comment: @Claudiu How does that even compile with the `xx += "x";` in a non-`mutable` lambda? On both gcc 4.9.2 and clang 3.5.0, the moved-from lambda prints nothing for me.

Comment: @Barry what example are you talking about? The ideone? Moved lambda prints on gcc49, gcc5 and clang. But the mutable business is a mystery, unless `std::string` has some weird `operator +=` that is `const` which makes no sense.

Comment: @Barry: `xx` is (also) a global... when moving all stuff in main, you got an error for modifying `xx` [demo](https://ideone.com/uxWjAz).

Comment: Hmm not sure. As Jarod did, I moved it to another function, it didn't let me modify `xx`, and when I ran it with that commented out the moved-from lambda printed nothing: https://ideone.com/vHE4fc . Maybe move semantics differ for globals?

Comment: That example is just invalid - `xx` doesn't have automatic storage, so the capture is invalid ("An entity that is designated by a simple-capture is said to be explicitly captured, and shall be this or a variable with automatic storage duration declared in the reaching scope of
the local lambda expression."). gcc warns on this, and probably ends up just not capturing - so the moved-from still prints because again `xx` is not a member of the lambda.

Comment: @Barry: Oh, okay, I get it. I got this warning in g++: "warning: capture of variable ‘xx’ with non-automatic storage duration [enabled by default]". So it probably disabled the capture and just used it as a global?

Comment: @Claudiu That's what it looks like. That's why you can modify it and it still exists after you move from it.

Comment: @Claudiu clang doesn't compile it ("error: `xx` cannot be captured because it does not have automatic storage duration")

Comment: @Barry even g++5 does it (-Wall -Wextra -pedantic), although it emits a warning. But now I see that indeed it is invalid to capture non-automatic vars.